# How to resolve Nginx dav PUT request failed on rename() with (13: Permission denied)?

Tags: permissions, nginx, webdav

When trying to `PUT` an index.html file in the root of an already existing folder, nginx fails with:

```
[crit] 1181#0: *1 rename() "/opt/spool/nginx/client_temp/1/0000000001"
to "/opt/share/www/domain.tld/index.html-3hlCQ9iE" failed (13:
Permission denied), client: 1.2.3.9, server: host.domain.tld, request:
"PUT /www/domain.tld/index.html-3hlCQ9iE HTTP/1.1", host: "172.21.2.2"
```

#### Environment

- Using `nginx-extras` 1.13.6-1 from `entware-3x` repo.
- running on Padavan firmware.
- ```
  $ grep www-rw /etc/passwd
  www-rw:x:1000:1001:Linux User,,,:/opt/share/www:/bin/sh

  $ grep www-w /etc/group
  www-w:x:1001:

  $ ls -l /opt/share/www
  drw-rw-r--    2 www-rw   www-w         4096 Feb  9 13:51 domain.tld

  $ ls -al /opt/share/www/domain.tld
  drw-rw-r--    2 www-rw   www-w         4096 Feb  9 13:51 .
  drwxr-xr-x    4 www-rw   www-w         4096 Feb  9 13:51 ..

  $ ls -l /opt/spool/nginx
  drwxrwxrwx    7 www-rw   root          4096 Feb  9 22:46 client_temp

  $ ls -l /opt/spool/nginx/client_temp
  drwx------    2 www-rw   www-w         4096 Feb  9 22:28 5
  ```
- Client: `Cyberduck/6.3.3.27341`
- Client-user: `www-rw`

Content of `nginx.conf`

```
user  www-rw www-w;
server {
    location /www {
        root                  /opt/share;

        client_body_temp_path /opt/spool/nginx/client_temp 1;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        # allow creating directories
        create_full_put_path  on;
        dav_access  user:rw  group:r  all:r;
        autoindex   on;
    }
}
```

#### Regression

- `user  nobody nogroup;`
- `dav_access  user:rw  group:r  all:r;`
- `#autoindex ...`
- Client-user: `admin`

What should I fix (in the permissions?) to resolve the Nginx dav permission denied errors?

Comment: Ownership/permissions on `/opt/spool/nginx/client_temp` ?

Comment: ls -al /opt/share/www/domain.tld might help

Comment: @ivanivan `ls -l /opt/spool/nginx` output is inserted. @GerardH.Pille `ls -al /opt/share/www/domain.tld` output is inserted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $ ls -l /opt/share/www
> drw-rw-r-- 2 www-rw www-w 4096 Feb 9 13:51 domain.tld
> ```

Not specifically tested, but... add `x` (execute) permissions there.

That is:

```
chmod 775 /opt/share/www/domain.tld
```

or

```
chmod 755 /opt/share/www/domain.tld
```

`x` (execute permission) on a directory is needed for some things that you might naively think should only need `w` (write permissions).

Source: [Francis Daly on Nginx mailing list 2018 February](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2018-February/055601.html)

Comment: Specifically, the x permission is needed to access the directory. The w permission is to create files, and r is for listing the contents.